# Use of infinitive form verb following "do" as emphasis

Tags: verbs, auxiliary-verbs

I’ve seen both versions of this sentence. Which one is correct? (Should both “matter” be infinitive or just the first one?)
Thanks

1. However, it did matter and matter a lot.
2. However, it did matter and mattered a lot.

Answer (score -1):

I would use the sentences but with a little change in the verb forms:

1. However, it did matter and ***matters*** a lot.

("matters" refers to the Present, 'now')

2. However, it did matter and has mattered a lot.

("has mattered" refers to the unfinished Past, 'up to now')

In any case only the first sentence of yours can be considered correct (as there are two homogeneous predicates and we can use one auxiliary 'did' for both).